# Generating sequence which each number is n times its predecessor

Tags: r, seq

How could I generate a sequence where each number is `n * previous_number`.

For example, in a sequence:

```
0.001 0.003 0.009 0.027
```

Each number is 3 times its predecessor. I was trying to use `seq` like:

```
seq(from = 0.001, by = 3, length.out = 10)
```

But it prints the output like:

```
0.001  3.001  6.001  9.001 12.001 15.001 18.001 21.001 24.001 27.001
```

Comment: `0.001*3^(1:10)`

Comment: @G5W Would miss 0.001

Comment: `0.001*3^(0:10)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numbers in Geometric Progression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094822/numbers-in-geometric-progression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Max said in a comment:

```
0.001*3^(0:10)
```

A decent code golf solution.

Comment: `0.001*c(1,cumprod(rep(3,10)))` isn't quite as compact (probably a little faster, if you care about microseconds)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little function:

```
seq_func <- function(x, m, len = 10) {
  return(x*m^(0:len))
}

seq_func(0.001, 3)
```

Which would yield

```
[1]  0.001  0.003  0.009  0.027  0.081  0.243  0.729  2.187  6.561 19.683
```